# How to display close button on the right hand side in the Tab

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

[image: Move the close button too right side]

As you can see currently the close button is at the top.

How can i place it on the right hand side ?

```
public class TabbedPaneTest extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage)
  {
    primaryStage.setTitle("TabPane Test");

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    tabPane.setStyle("-fx-tab-min-height: 100");
    tabPane.setRotateGraphic(true);
    tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS);

    tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab("Tab 1"), tab("Tab 2"));
    tabPane.setSide(Side.LEFT);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tabPane, 400, 200));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  static Tab tab(String labelText)
  {
    Tab tab = new Tab();
    Label label = new Label(labelText);
    label.setRotate(90);
    tab.setGraphic(new StackPane(label));
    tab.setContent(new Label("       " + labelText + " content"));
    return tab;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be a little bit hacky.

Based on the [CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#tabpane) of `TabPane` and the source code of `TabPaneSkin`: a `Tab` contains a `StackPane` that contains a `Label`, the close `Button` and the focus indicator. This `StackPane` has the style class `tab-container`.

So you can rotate this `StackPane` in CSS:

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab > .tab-container {
   -fx-rotate:90;
}
```

After rotating the `StackPane` I have noticed, that the focus indicator is handled differently, so that one must be also rotated (it has the style class `focus-indicator`).

```
.tab-pane > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab * .focus-indicator {
   -fx-rotate:-90;
}
```

**An example**, that the same as yours, just the style-sheet is added, and the `Label` on the `Tab` is not rotated anymore:

```
public class TabbedPaneTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("TabPane Test");

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.setStyle("-fx-tab-min-height: 100");
        tabPane.setRotateGraphic(true);
        tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.ALL_TABS);

        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab("Tab 1"), tab("Tab 2"));
        tabPane.setSide(Side.LEFT);

        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 400, 200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toString());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    static Tab tab(String labelText) {
        Tab tab = new Tab();
        Label label = new Label(labelText);

        tab.setGraphic(new StackPane(label));
        tab.setContent(new Label("       " + labelText + " content"));
        return tab;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But you can also use this approach without using a graphic on the `Tab`:

```
static Tab tab(String labelText) {
    Tab tab = new Tab(labelText);
    tab.setContent(new Label("       " + labelText + " content"));
    return tab;
}
```

*This will produce a `TabPane` like on the picture:*

[image]

Comment: How do i add CSS directly in code without external stylesheet? `Scene` doesn't have `setStyle()` method.

Comment: @VenkataRaju You can't (at least not without some truly ugly hacks). Use an external stylesheet. That is better practice anyway.

Comment: @James_D Yeah, expected :). But it would've been useful for quick testing.

Comment: A litter shorter version to add style sheet is `scene.getStylesheets().add("application.css")`;

Comment: As long as the stylesheet is stored in the root package of you application:)

Comment: @DVarga I have set the label background (in the Tab) and found that lot of unused space is there. How to reduce that? Removing this did not help `tabPane.setStyle("-fx-tab-min-height: 100");` or setting the `-fx-tab-max-width`